# Unity 5.4 C# Animation Play/Stop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to play/stop animations with C# codes but they didn't worked, Javascript code work (legacy mode). I hope someone know where is problem.

C#:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayStop : MonoBehaviour

{
  public GameObject Cube;


  void PS()
  {
     GetComponent<Animation>().Play();
  }
 }
```

---

JS:

```
var Cube : GameObject; 
Cube.GetComponent.<Animation>().Play();
```

[C# Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRpkl.png)

[JS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8LAp.png)

Comment: You said the Javascript code works but the Javascript  code in your question is not even valid....

Comment: Is screenshot enough to see that works?, It work without any warning and error

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-animation.html

Comment: but C# version of code don't work. and i don't know why.

Comment: This is what the valid Javascript code should look like `Cube.GetComponent.<Animation>().Play();`

Comment: Yes wrong type. but JS is working problem is C# side.

Comment: I tested, "Cube.GetComponent<Animation>().Play();" in C# side, Unity show no error but it still didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that mentioned C# and JS code you wrote are not equivalent.
In C# code you call `GetComponent<Animation>` to search in gameObject to which `PlayStop` script is attached to, while in JS script you are searching with `GetComponent<Animation>` in `Cube` gameObject you dragged from inspector.

You should try:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayStop : MonoBehaviour

{
    public GameObject Cube;


    void PS()
    {
        //Will search in Cube game object for component of Animation type
        Cube.GetComponent<Animation>().Play();
    }
}
```

To run code inside `PS()` on application run, rename it to `Start()` or move code from inside of it to new method and name it `Start()`.

To run `PS()` on button click, click `+` in `OnClick` section of Button in Inspector, drag your `PlayStop` script to box on the left and choose the function you want to call on click from dropdown, like this:

[image]

Comment: I tested it and added it to Cube, in unity editor dropped Cube to GameObject field of this script, but still it didn't worked.

Comment: How are you calling `PS()` method? Button or what? How did you call it with JS script?

Comment: I attached a screenshot, if i remove C# and add JS component to Cube with this settings after run cube will turn right(animation play).

Comment: If you want the animation to play on `Run`, you need to put the code inside `Start()` method or simply rename `PS()` to `Start()`.

Comment: I'm not calling PS() i just add JS code to cube and add Cube to GameObject field. second screenshot i attached show playing animation in runtime.

Comment: Now could you tell me how can i do this job with button click?

Comment: I added another two function and now i have access to them with buttons.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Basically you need to add new OnClick in Button Component in inspector, then drag `PlayStop` script on left and choose your function from dropdown on right.

Comment: Answer was true, i don't know why he voted negative.